# How to test cordova contacts plugin with CADT or inside CDE?

Tags: cordova, google-chrome-app, chrome-dev-editor

How do I test my chrome mobile app using chrome-dev-editor if it has the contacts API?

If I use the "run" option in CDE, then `navigator.cotacts` is undefined. The same thing happens if I use "realtime deploy" with my phone.

Is there a way to solve this inside CDE? If not - it seems that CADT does not yet support all of cordova default plugins, however you can build it yourself with the additional plugins. How is this done?

Answer (score 0):

Probably. You are right.

You can file an issue to https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/chrome-app-developer-tool